# How to calculate the determinant of a non-singular matrix (n*n) using elementary transformation in C?

Tags: c, matrix

I would like to transform my matrix to either a upper triangular (or a lower triangular matrix) using elementary transformations and then multiply the diagonal elements to find the determinant of the given non singular matrix.
I am a beginner in c programming and have written the following codes for calculating the determinant of a non singular matrix. The codes are

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<math.h>     
        void main()
        {
                int i,j,k,r;
                float mat[20][20],temp,diag=1;
                printf("enter the order of the square matrix\n\n");
                scanf("%d",&r);
                for(i=0;i<r;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<r;j++)
                    {
                        printf("enter the (%d , %d)th entry",i+1,j+1);
                        scanf("%f",&mat[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                printf("The matrix we have entered is\n\n ");
                for(i=0;i<r;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<r;j++)
                    {
                        printf("\t%f",mat[i][j]);

                    }
                 printf("\n");
                }
                for(i=0;i<r-1;i++)
                {
                    for(j=i+1;j<r;j++)
                    {
                        temp=mat[j][i]/mat[i][i];
                        for(k=0;k<r;k++)
                        {
                            mat[j][k]=mat[j][k]-temp*mat[i][k];
                        }
                    }
                }
              for(i=0;i<r;i++)
                {

                    diag=diag*mat[i][i];

                }
                printf("\n\nThe value of the determinant is %f",diag);
        }
```

This works fine for any non singular matrix except the ones that have a zero as its (1,1)th element (ie the first diagonal element).I can understand that this happening due to my

```
  temp=mat[j][i]/mat[i][i];
```

code.But this code is necessary for calculating the determinant.So there must be some ways to change   the program such that it runs for any non singular matrix.How can I edit my program to fulfill my  purpose? Thanks for your help.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: [Blas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms)

Comment: See Numerical Recipes: http://nr.com

Comment: The [Gauss Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) is simple to understand and uses only elementary transformations.

Comment: Gaussian elimination if you insist on elementary operations. If not you could use cofactor expansions

Comment: The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) is good for linear algebra in C.  You could use `gsl_linalg_LU_decomp` to find the LU factorisation, then `gsl_linalg_LU_det` to calculate the determinant (see [the documentation for LU decomposition](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/LU-Decomposition.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to find the upper triangular  matrix and then find the determinant. You may find this code usefull:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    float  matrix[10][10], ratio, det;
    int i, j, k, n;
    printf("Enter order of matrix: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the matrix: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    /* Conversion of matrix to upper triangular */
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(j>i){
                ratio = matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i];
                for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
                    matrix[j][k] -= ratio * matrix[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    det = 1; //storage for determinant
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        det *= matrix[i][i];
    printf("The determinant of matrix is: %.2f\n\n", det);
    return 0;
}
```

Taken from [here](http://easy-learn-c-language.blogspot.in/2013/02/numerical-methods-determinant-of-nxn.html)